# Why substract vector::size with store it to a variable first and without return different result?

Tags: c++, vector, size

Size of the vector is 5, then I want to subtract it by 6. It should return -1, but the first try which I don't store the size in a variable doesn't return -1. It's return bunch of random number. Why is this happen? It looks exactly the same to me, with or without storing the size first to a variable. Both should return -1.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> arr(5);

    cout << arr.size() - 6 << endl;

    int size = arr.size();
    cout << size - 6 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not random. Look at the documentation to see what `size()` returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of `arr.size()` is an *unsigned* integral type, most commonly `std::size_t`.  When you subtract 6 from it, the value underflows and wraps around to the largest integer the size can store because the type cannot store negative values.

When you store the result in a variable, you are also converting it to `int` which is a *signed* type and *is* able to store negative values.  No underflow happens and the expected value of -1 can be represented.

If you store the value preserving its type, you will observe the same thing because `size` will also be of an unsigned type:

```
auto size = arr.size();
```

([Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30df5af5c912ebba))